# How can I attach a custom property to a list item?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to attach an enumeration value to a list item.

```
<ul>
    <li>monday</li>
    <li>tuesday</li>
    <li>wednesday</li>
    <li>thursday</li>
    <li>friday</li>
    <li>saturday</li>
    <li>sunday</li>
</ul>

Day = Object.freeze(
{   
    monday    : 1,
    tuesday   : 2,
    wednesday : 3,
    thursday  : 4,
    friday    : 5,
    saturday  : 6,
    sunday    : 7,
});
```

I would like to do something like that:

```
<li day="monday">monday</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is fine in HTML5 but you could use `data-day` if you want to be more semantically correct.